# ReactNative useState with array of objects

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am building a form field validation object. I am using useState to track both the value in each field on the form and the type of field for validation ie email, text, password. I can do this with two separate hooks (one for the value and one for the state). I am attempting to put those together in an object. This is where the issue occurs.

The field name is the key for each field. The object looks like the following

```
      fName : {
          text: 'John',
          colType: 'text'
          }

      lName : {
          text: 'Doe',
          colType: 'text'
          }

      hairColor : {
          text: 'Brown'
          colType: 'text'

      birthDate : {
          text: '02/02/2010'
          colType: 'date'
```

As you can see the validation will be based on the type of field. This validation will happen onSubmit of the form. This component will be reusable for all forms. I am attempting it to make it generic for that reason.

Here is what I am attempting to use for the setter function

```
    setValues({...values,
        [name] : {
            text : [text],
            colType : [colType]
            }
    });
```

I am having an issue destructuring this to get the text and the colType to validate the text based on the colType. [name] is the name of the object to be validated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correctly using the dynamic key `[name]`. However, you are trying to set an Array with one item, the variable `text` or `colType` ( `text : [text]` means set an Array of one object to the `text` field of the parent object ).

Instead, it should be:

```
setValues({...values,
    [name] : {
        text : text,
        colType : colType
    }
});
```

or:

```
setValues({...values,
    [name] : {
        text,
        colType
    }
});
```

Comment: I see what you are saying and I have made those changes and that part works fine. The next issue is how to destructure these this object into variables. I would like to extract all three variables name, text and colType so that I can use them in the validation.

Comment: Can you give an example? What does the validator function look like? Are you trying to get the text and colType based on a string like `"fName"`? If so, you can do `const {text, colType} = values[name]`.

Comment: PJohnson thanks very much. What you have given me works great when I know the value of name, const {text, colType} = values[name] . The issue I have now is I don't know the names of the textInput objects. I would like to loop thru all of the 'names' in the object 'values' to get the 'text' and 'colTypes' for each 'name'. Sorry for the confusing naming. I can rename the objects for a better example if needed. My end goal is to have a generic validation that will validate all of the textInput in a form based on colType.

Comment: name in the above is a variable, which means you can use it in a loop. How about `Object.keys(values).forEach(name => {// use name here})` ? This takes all the keys (names) as strings and stores them in an array, then you loop through them and do whatever you need using `const {text, colType} = values[name]`

Answer (score 0):

Using the above example in the question:

To place values into the useState hook:

```
const [values, setValues] = useState([]);

setValues({...values,
    [name] : {
        text,
        colType
    }
});
```

To read values out of the useState hook including the key:

```
const entries = Object.entries(values); 

entries.forEach (function (arrayItem) {
    const {text, colType} = values[arrayItem[0]]; // arrayItem[0] = [name] text = text value colType = colType value for the key which is [name]
    ... the rest of the code to validate the entries for all of the columns on the form
})
```

There might be a better/more readable way to extract these out but This works. If you have a better way please post it I would be glad to update mine. Thanks to PJohnson for the help